# VLC does not play some specific MKV file anymore from my sambashare folders

Tags: samba, video, vlc

VLC 3.0.8 worked perfectly since last week, but lately it does not want to play files in a certain folder from a samba server installed on OMV on a raspberry pi. It is weird since it will play them when they are copied to desktop.

I should say that it actually loads the video but it takes 2 mins to open a video of 100MB. It would take less than 30 seconds to just copy it on local

Comment: When you try to play the file from vlc what happens? What error message do you get? What messages are written in the samba log files on the server? Can you copy the file from the samba share to the device running vlc?

Comment: 1. VLC just loads the file for 2 full minutes (files are approx 100mb each). 2.I actually don't get any, since apparently it actually loads the file. 3. How do I check the log files? 4. Yes, I can copy them to desktop or elsewhere which usually is much faster than just wait 2 minutes